# ee.Algorithms.If throwing both cases in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, if-else

I'm trying to work with the ee.Algorithms.If in the sense that:
if list = 0(i.e. not containing any points within a buffer) -> do a function()
else (buffer is containing points)-> do a function()

My problem is that both my true and false cases are thrown which leads to nothing is happening. 
I know about the server side vs client side issue and that that is one of my problems. However, I don't know how to deal with it. Maybe I can get a helping hand on that? see code below.

```
var VMAsize = VMA.size();
ee.Algorithms.If(VMAsize= 0, size0 , sizeint);
  var sizeint = function(){
    var VMA_regionobj_list = VMApoints.toList(VMA.size());
    var VMA_regionname_list = tools.featureCollection.propertyValues(VMApoints, 'Title');
    var VMA_regionsummary_list = tools.featureCollection.propertyValues(VMApoints, 'Summary');
    var VMA_regionupdatetime_list = tools.featureCollection.propertyValues(VMApoints, 'UpdateTime');
    var VMA_regionauthor_link_list = tools.featureCollection.propertyValues(VMApoints, 'Author');
    VMA_regionpanel.clear();
    var VMA_regionselect = ui.Select({
      items: VMA_regionname_list.sort().getInfo(),
      onChange: function(key) {
        var index = VMA_regionname_list.indexOf(key);
        VMA_regionpanel_info.style().set('shown', true);
        VMA_regionname.setValue(key);
        VMA_regionsummary.setValue('Announcement: '+VMA_regionsummary_list.get(index).getInfo());
        VMA_regionauthor_link.setValue('Web page: ');
        VMA_regionupdatetime.setValue('Update time: '+VMA_regionupdatetime_list.get(index).getInfo());
        VMA_regionlink.setValue(VMA_regionauthor_link_list.get(index).getInfo());
        VMA_regionselect.setValue(null, false);
      }
    });
  VMA_regionselect.setPlaceholder('Choose an VMA...');
  VMA_regionselect.style().set({margin: '0 0 1% 0', width: '98%'});
  VMA_regionpanel.add(VMA_regionselect);
  return VMA_regionselect;
  };

  var size0 = function(){
    VMA_regionpanel.clear();
    var VMA_regionselect = ui.Select({
      onChange: function(key) {
        VMA_regionpanel_info.style().set('shown', true);
        VMA_regionsummary.setValue('Announcement: There are no announcements within this area'); 
        VMA_regionauthor_link.setValue('Web page: ');
        VMA_regionselect.setValue(null, false);
      }
    });
  VMA_regionselect.setPlaceholder('Choose an VMA...');
  VMA_regionselect.style().set({margin: '0 0 1% 0', width: '98%'});
  VMA_regionpanel.add(VMA_regionselect);
  return VMA_regionselect;
  }
```

Comment: I would say make your condition (VMAsize) a client-side object (use getInfo or evaluate) and make a client-side javascript IF/ELSE statement.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see in the first two lines

```
var VMAsize = VMA.size();
ee.Algorithms.If(VMAsize= 0, size0 , sizeint);
```

You are doing VMAsize=0
This is wrong. First of all, it sets the value of VMAsize as 0 not compare it to zero. Secondly, as you mentioned it is a server side object and is only a list of invocations at the client side. In order to compare te VMAsize to zero you can do

```
VMAsize.eq(0)
```

You can use this as

```
ee.Algorithms.If(VMAsize.eq(0), size0() , sizeint());
```

This should at least let you propagate through the if block to the right function. Another thing is that "ee.Algorithms.If" is supposed to return an object and not execute a function so it should be something like.

```
var returnObj = ee.Algorithms.If(VMAsize.eq(0), size0() , sizeint());
print(returnObj)
```

or something like that.

Edit: fixed the function calls within If i.e. added missing brackets.

Comment: Thank you @Nishanta, it feels like this is on the right track. However, I want to add a selector (VMAregion_select) to the map depending on if it is a true or false case. Do you think it is possible through the functions that are called in the Algorithms.If?

Comment: Well generally, the problem with that is UI elements (generally) do not take server objects to initialize as on client side they are just stacked invocations. So even if you return the select object itself or return settings for select and initialize the ui element, it will not work. I think a workaround is that you can use 'evaluate' on a server side object to bring it to client side and then initialize the UI element. as shown here
https://code.earthengine.google.com/a68195389bf4c3fd32d00c9965d0ba56

i'd recommend you use a callback function so that he UI doesn't freeze while its running.

Comment: thank you for your help. Now I could make it work with your example.